# How do I save the values of checkboxes in a form into a single MySQL field?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html

I have a form where i have many music genres. An artist can be singing under many genres. I have put the genres in checkboxes. Now i need to store the values of the checkboxes in to a single field.

Can some one help me out with some code snippet as i am new to php programming?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Reagan :)

Answer (score 4):

In general you shouldn't be doing it that way. Your database would not be [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), and that would make it difficult to build queries on the genre field.

It would be a better idea if you would have a table called `artists`, and a table called `genres`. Then you would define the relationship between the artists and the genres in another table `artists_genres`, which table would simply holds an `artist_id` and a `genre_id`. You would still be able to have multiple genres for the same artist.

For example, consider the table structure as defined below:

```
 TABLE artists
 -------------

 artist_id          name             surname
 1                  Alicia           Keys
 2                  Mariah           Carey
 ...


 TABLE genres
 ------------

 genre_id           name
 1                  R&B
 2                  pop
 3                  hip hop
 4                  dance
 ...


 TABLE artists_genres
 --------------------

 artist_id          genre_id
 1                  1
 1                  2
 1                  3
 2                  1
 2                  2 
 2                  4
 ...
```

In this case, you would be able to build simple queries such as:

```
SELECT 
    artists.name, artists.surname
FROM
    artists
INNER JOIN
    artists_genres ON (artists_genres.artist_id = artists.artist_id)
INNER JOIN
    genres ON (genres.genre_id = artists_genres.genre_id)
WHERE
    genre.name = 'pop';
```

The above would be quite difficult to achieve if the genres of your artists are stored in a single field in the `artists` table. Apart from the difficulty, it will probably be slow and inefficient, especially if you will be having many records.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to store multiple values in a single field - this will make searching/retrieval needlessly painful.

Either use a field per genre, or better still use a 'genres' table and 'artist_genres' lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [serialize](http://www.php.net/serialize)/[unserialize](http://www.php.net/unserialize), but you shouldn't save serialized data to a database.

You won't be able to use database functions on it (searching, ordering, etc.) i.e.

Answer (score 1):

You could serialize the data, for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="Genre1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="Genre2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="Genre3"/>
```

PHP:

```
// Don't forget to escape the POST-values
$genre = serialize($_POST['genre']);
$query = "INSERT INTO database (genre) VALUES ('" . $genre . "')";
if(mysql_query($query)){
   // Success
}
```

You can get the data back with:

```
$genres = unserialize($serializedGenre);
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a [SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) datatype that would lend itself well to storing a set of checkboxes in a single column.